# How to generate a dict of column values from an SQLAlchemy ORM class?

Tags: python, orm, sqlalchemy, python-2.7

I have a need to serialize certain columns of several ORM based classes. I want to default to the columns specified in the creation of the ORM class.

```
class AXSection(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'axsection'
    __table_args__ = {'mysql_engine':'ISAM', 'mysql_charset':'utf8'}
    id = Column(BigInteger, primary_key=True)
    enabled = Column(String(1), nullable=False, default='T')
    pages = relationship('AXPage', backref='axsection')a
    name = Column(String(255), nullable=False)
```

How do I write a method to return the names of the columns?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The **table** attribute contains the list of column names.  To print the column name associated with your example AXSection type, use:

```
print AXSection.__table__.columns
```

Results in:

```
['axsection.id', 'axsection.enabled', 'axsection.name']
```

Comment: There's a typo in the answer. AXSection.__table__.colums should be AXSection.__table__.columns

Couldn't fix it because stackoverflow requires at least a 6 character edit.